# jQuery UI Sortable - update item data-id attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Suppose I have the following sortable object:

```
<ul class="photos ui-sortable">
    <li class="photo" data-id="1"></li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="2"></li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="3"></li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="4"></li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="5"></li>
    <li class="photo" data-id="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Upon sorting, the `data-id` attribute of all the items need to be updated with their new positions.

I tried this:

```
$('.photos').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $(ui.item).attr('data-id', ui.item.index()+1);
    }
});
```

But it only updates the data-id of the item that was moved, and not the others. How can I do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this? The items are indexed by their order in the DOM...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `update` event, inside of there just loop over each `.photo` and set the `data-id` according to its current index:

```
$('.photos').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $('.photo').each(function(i) { 
           $(this).data('id', i + 1); // updates the data object
           $(this).attr('data-id', i + 1); // updates the attribute
        });
    }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDf44/15/)

Comment: Yes it does , he just haven't updated the data attribute .. in fiddle

Comment: @Runcorn My bad I see, nice job

Comment: This is nice solution. But what if I remove(delete) any list item. Suppose i drop 5 item in the droppable list (Having data-id='1'...so on) and delete forth element. How to re-arrange ids?

Comment: just trigger sortable's update function when the item is deleted

Comment: Even in the fiddle, the data-id doesn't seem to update when dragging?

Comment: @Nathan that's because in the fiddle only the data object is being updated. jQuery uses the attribute to populate the data object initially, after which there's no association between the two. Here's a fiddle where the attribute is also updated: http://jsfiddle.net/sk3r8fae/

Answer (score 4):

You are using the stop method `ui` which returns current item on move. So basically you have to iterate through all the items and manually put the data attribute value ,

```
$('.photos').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $(".ui-sortable li").each(function(i, el){
               $(el).prop('data-id',$(el).index()+1);
        });
    }
});
```

### And here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/923/)